# Для устройства не установлены драйверы. (Код 28) Эта операция требует интерактивного оконного терминала

Tags: windows, iphone, usb, драйвер

Во время обновления iPhone через iTunes, отсоединил кабель и ввел телефон в Recovery Mode, после чего iTunes перестал видеть iPhone.

Через Диспетчер Устройств Windows пытылся обновить(удалить) драйвер.

Apple Mobile Device (Recovery Mode), Apple Recovery (iBoot) USB driver для iPhone на Windows 10 не устанавливается и выдает ошибку:

Для устройства не установлены драйверы. (Код 28) Эта операция требует интерактивного оконного терминала.

iTunes переустанавливал дважды (не видит iPhone).

Как можно установить драйвера?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

разархивировал установочный пакет **iTunes6464Setup.exe**,

запустил **AppleMobileDeviceSupport6464.msi**, драйвера установились,

iTunes обновил iPhone успешно и вывел из Recovery Mode